# tkinter: How to change labels inside the program itself

Tags: python, tkinter

I was asked to edit my code so I decided to include the entire calculator script

> ```
> from tkinter import *
> global choice 
> choice = 0
>
>
> #Program
> def calculate(*event):
>     if choice == 1:
>         try:
>             add1 = ccalc1.get()
>             add2 = ccalc2.get()
>         except:
>             no = Label(app, text="You must use a number").grid(row=0, column=0)
>         answ = add1 + add2         
>         answer = Label(app, text = answ).grid(row=1, column=0)
>     elif choice == 2:
>         try:
>             sub1 = ccalc1.get()
>             sub2 = ccalc2.get()
>         except:
>             no = Label(app, text="You must use a number").grid(row=1, column=0)
>         answ = sub1 - sub2         
>         answer = Label(app, text = answ).grid(row=1, column=0) 
> def choice2():
>     global choice
>     choice = 2       
> #End Program
> #GUI
> #Window Info
> calc = Tk()
> calc.title("Calculator")
> calc.geometry("200x140")
> #End Window Info
>
> #Build Window
> app = Frame(calc)
> app.grid()
> ccalc1 = IntVar()
> ccalc2 = IntVar()
>
> #Widgets
> if choice == 0:
>     welcome = Label(app, text="Select a choice")
> elif choice == 2:
>     welcome.config(text="Subtraction")
> calcbox1 = Entry(app,textvariable=ccalc1)
> calcbox2 = Entry(app,textvariable=ccalc2)
> submit = Button(app, text="CALCULATE", command = calculate)
>
> welcome.grid(row=0,column=0)
> calcbox1.grid(row=2, column=0)
> calcbox2.grid(row=3, column=0)
> submit.grid(row=4, column=0)
> calc.bind('<Return>', calculate)
> #End Widgets
>
> #Menu
> menu=Menu(calc)
> #Operations
> filemenu = Menu(menu,tearoff=0)
> filemenu.add_command(label="Subtract", command = choice2)  
> menu.add_cascade(label="Operations",menu=filemenu)     
> calc.config(menu=menu)
> calc.mainloop()
> #End GUI
> ```

what wrong is that the welcome label text wont change accordingly.

Update: I included the entire calculator code

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please double check the code you've posted here. I tried running it and got `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`.

Comment: Updated to include the entire calculator. It works for me

Comment: What should happen is that 'Select a choice' changes to 'subtraction' after the choice is chosen in the menu

Comment: Note that the `if choice == 0` code executes exactly once, the instant the code starts. Since that's the only time you call `welcome.config`, it makes sense that the label doesn't change in response to any kind of user input.

Comment: @Kevin how else should I handle this then? I tried wrapping it in a while statement. but that causes it to not run at all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you expect to happen. For example, look at this code:

```
#Widgets
if choice == 0:
    welcome = Label(app, text="Select a choice")
elif choice == 2:
    welcome.config(text="Subtraction")
```

This code will only ever execute once, and choice will always be zero since that's what you initialize it to. It executes once because it's not in a function and not in a loop, so as python parses the code it will run it and move to the next line. That block of text will never be processed a second time.

If you want the label to change when the user selects a menu item, you'll need to execute that code inside the `choice2` function:

```
def choice2():
    global choice
    choice = 2
    welcome.config(text="Subtraction")
```

Comment: In the main post Kevin pointed that out, I guess I misunderstood how if worked. How would I go about having that block of code look out for any changes? Would making it a while loop accomplish that? I tried that before posting this question but it caused the program to not run, it only brought up a empty terminal window.

Comment: @user3763447: what do you mean "look out for any changes"? The way a GUI works is that you set up bindings, or associate commands with widgets. When the event happens or the widget is invoked, the associated command is run. You're already calling `choice2` when the menu is selected, so that's a perfect place to update the label.

Comment: @user3763447: you do not need to set up a loop -- that's what `mainloop` is. Mainloop is an infinite loop that waits for events and the calls the associated function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried putting it in the function but perhaps I mistyped something. I'll try it again when I get home and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your way worked after all. 

If I could I would up vote you.